# List of Records in F#?

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, records

How do you work with a List of Records in F#? How would you even pass that as an argument in a function?  I want to do something like this:

```
type Car = {
  Color : string;
  Make : string;
  }

let getRedCars cars =
  List.filter (fun x -> x.Color = "red") cars;

let car1 = { Color = "red"; Make = "Toyota"; }
let car2 = { Color = "black"; Make = "Ford"; }
let cars = [ car1; car2; ]
```

I need a way to tell my function that "cars" is a List of Car records.

Comment: Would the problem not be the `car1` and `car2` declarations not being of `type Car` - so it cannot automatically determine the type signature.

Comment: Your code works just fine. The inferred signature of `getRedCars` is `Car list -> Car list`. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: I guess it does work. Seems that VS thought it was an error at first, but latest compile it works. This also works (wonder if it helps the compiler?): (fun (x : Visit) -> x.Color = "red") cars

Comment: I tested it too and it does work fine, but I am surprised that the single `;` at the end of the body of `getRedCars` is valid. Using verbose syntax I would except only `;;` for a top-level declaration, or ` in ... ` for a local expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works just fine. It can also be written:

```
let getRedCars cars =
  List.filter (function {Color = "red"} -> true | _ -> false) cars
```

If you're ever concerned the wrong signature is being inferred, you can add type annotations. For example:

```
let getRedCars (cars:Car list) : Car list = //...
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the type annotation for lists. Thanks so much.

Comment: @StephenSwensen: That's good for him to know. Also, section 5.2 of the [Component Design Guidelines (PDF)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) recommends using the prefix notation, with four exceptions: `list`, `option`, `array`, and `ref`.

Comment: *(deleted and reposted this comment since had major error mixing up prefix and postfix)* @Matthew: note that the postfix syntax used for parameterized types is inherited from ML, but you can also use the .NET prefix syntax: `list<Car>`.